# Integrar Jquery y Bootstrap en Angular (Symfony)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, symfony, angular

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con symfony y angular, para mi sorpresa, que cuando llego a la parte de angular, e intento implementar bootstrap y jquery, me dice que no es posible cargar los recursos, el mensaje de error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
Refused to apply style from 'recurso local' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

y lo mismo para los scripts:

```
Refused to apply scripts from 'recurso local' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

He añadido en el fichero .angular-cli.json, el codigo correspondiente:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
```

en el index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src = "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hasta incluso he instalado a traves de consola el jquery y bootstrap, y he puesto en el archivo app.component.ts:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, ya la verdad no se que hacer. Saludos y gracias

Edito: Foto de la estructura de carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un pantallazo con la estructura de carpetas?

Comment: Claro, edito Kiko_L

Comment: No termino de verlo claro pero, ¿puede ser que Node_modules esté un nivel por encima de tu index.html?

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

       <script type="text/javascript" src = "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src = "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: No puedes poner URLs así, apuntando a node_modules, en tu HTML resultante: esos ficheros no estarán presentes en tu servidor, son dependencias de desarrollo. Por otro lado, si quieres usar jQuery con Angular, es señal de que no tienes algunas cosas claras con Angular

Comment: Pues la verdad no, no tengo mucha idea, porque acabo de empezar a desarrollar en estos frameworks, y si pregunto por aqui es por algo... De todas formas creo que lo he resuelto omitiendo los enlaces en el html y dejandolo solo en el angular.cli